# Failed to set alertDialog item into listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-alertdialog

2 textview inside each of listview item, 1st for listItem and 2nd for choice. The real I need is to set 2nd textView in every listview as same as choice selected and save its value. When I select on “ItemSelected 5” and choose “Choice 3”, It will give me in the listview:

```
ItemSelected 5
Choice 3
```

And its value is 0.75. 
My problem is when I select in “ItemSelected 6” and choose “Choice 4”, It got Force closed. Here is the LogCat

```
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at id.app.diagnosagangguankehamilan.GejalaPilih$1$1.onClick(GejalaPilih.java:59) //Here is refer to (*_*)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-06 23:13:18.742: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And It is My code:

```
final Double[] value = new Double[25];

    //After OnCreate

        String[] listItem = {“ItemSelected 1”,”ItemSelected 2”,”ItemSelected 3”,”ItemSelected 4”,”ItemSelected 5”,”ItemSelected 6”,…,”ItemSelected 30”};

        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewItemSelected); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new GejalaPilihAdapter(this, listItem);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemSelectedClickListener(new OnItemSelectedClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelectedClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position,long arg3) {


                final CharSequence[] choice = {"Choice 1","Choice 2","Choice 3","Choice 4"};

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                alert.setTitle("Select Choice");
                alert.setSingleChoiceItemSelecteds(choice, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int itemSelected) {

                        TextView textView = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.textViewChoice); //(*_*)
                        textView.setText(choice[itemSelected]);                     

                        switch (itemSelected) {
                        case 0:
                            value[position] = 0.25;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            value[position] = 0.5;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            value[position] = 0.75;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            value[position] = 1.0;
                            break;
                        default:
                            value[position] = 0.0;
                            break;
                        }

                        Log.d("","Choice["+position+"] = "+choice[itemSelected]);

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog al = alert.create();
                al.show();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `listView.getChildAt(position)` because when you click on a listview item, it already brings its view. Check the `View arg1` paramter in `onItemSelectedClick()` method. You can make the paramter as final

```
 public void onItemSelectedClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View arg1, final int position,long arg3) {
```

and use it to get the textview

```
TextView textView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textViewChoice);
```